# Cassandra in Docker and versioning

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra and now I'm trying to launch cluster in test mode.

Currently, each Cassandra node running in Docker container using `--net=host` option and seeds and listening addresses resolved by FQDNs. So far so good.

But there is a question. Each container has volume binded to `$CASSANDRA_HOME/data`. Docker images have been builded as CentOS images which download Cassandra tar and configs injected in Dockerfile.

Now, let's say I want to build new version of image, where I just want to change heap size in cassandra-env.sh (or just try shiny new metric scraper).

Any Cassandra upgrading tutorial say `preserve cassandra config` but what serve as identifier for node? Is it IP address, FQDN? What config is defining for cluster to know that I'm not adding new node? Seeds and addresses? Or rack name in rackdc.property matters too? How node will decide that it should skip autobootstrapping phase (and will it be skipped)?

And about data. In cassandra_home/data lies commit_log folder. Should I keep it there and when new image start it'll use all that saved? Or it can be problem and it's better to not bind commit_log? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**what serve as identifier for node?**

*It is the IP of the node. Cassandra nodes communicate with each other on listen_address.*

**What config is defining for cluster to know that I'm not adding new node?**

*If it is not listen address (other addresses) that you are updating  then you are not adding new node.*

**Seeds and addresses?**

*Seeds are used by new nodes to bootstrap. They want to know what is the topology of the cluster. They connect with one of the seed node while starting up for information.
Addresses
Listen_Address - used for internode communication between C* nodes
RPC_Address - use for client server communication
Broadbast_address - for public connectivity, multi site connectivity.*

**rack name in rackdc.property matters too?**

*Rack is logical grouping done for data replication across regions or host machines.*

**How node will decide that it should skip autobootstrapping phase (and will it be skipped)?**

*IF by autobootsrtapping you mean it should start with streaming in data from other nodes, then set auto_bootstrap property to false. By default it is true.*

Comment: What do you mean by streaming? Is it should catch up with later data from replicas? Yes. Is it should get new token range? Of course not.

Comment: Streaming is the term used when one C* node sends data to other C* node or receive data from other C* node. Whenever a node is added to a cluster, you start the node, it is assigned new tokens and since new tokens will be taken from the cluster only so it will also take the data from other nodes(streaming). You have the option to disable that sttreaming when adding a node to cluster.

Comment: I'm not adding node. I want it to be the same node on same server but with slightly changed config (heap size for example). Should I set auto bootstrap to false in that case?

Comment: Just change the properties in respective files. Also dont change address properties. No need to set auto_bootstrap to false.  You can try on test environment all these things.